# Replace bold text with <b>...</b> in MS Word without macros

Tags: microsoft-word, html

I have a text with bold & italic font and I need to convert it to html. 
First, I need to convert bold text to **...**. I found some 
solutions, but all of them uses VBA code. Is it possible to fix it with search&replace (it is possible to search for bold text in Word 2007 for example).

Comment: This did not work for me
But the same promise is hold here(https://superuser.com/questions/219527/replace-b-b-with-bold-in-ms-word-with-macros)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tested in Word 2010:

- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
  to invoke Word’s “Find and Replace” dialog
- Click on the “More >>” button
- Leave the “Find what:” field *blank*
  (or ***set*** it blank, if necessary)
- With the cursor in the “Find what:” field,
  click “Format → Font” and set “Font style” to “Bold”
- In the “Replace with:” put `<b>^&</b>`
- With the cursor in the “Replace with:” field,
  click “Format → Font” and set “Font style” to “Not Bold”<sup>1</sup>
- Click “Replace All”

This will put the tags around your bold text, and change it to non-bold.
__________________
<sup>1</sup> Suggested by [MalcolmTW](https://superuser.com/users/1268220/malcolmtw) in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1622104/150988) (now deleted).

Comment: Any idea why my word 2010 changes *Word* to `Word<i></i>` instead of `<i>Word</i>` when I try your example

Comment: Any ideas if there is a way to do this in Excel?  I tried this method but it doesn't seem Excel interprets  this correctly:   ^&.