# Replace <b>…</b> with bold in MS Word with macros

Tags: microsoft-word, html, macros

I have seen the posting for 
[Replace bold text with **…** in MS Word without macros](https://superuser.com/questions/171314/replace-bold-text-with-b-b-in-ms-word-without-macros).

How can I do the opposite?  How can I open up a .txt file that has html tags in it like

```
here is <i>italic</i> text here and then I also have <b>bold text</b> over here
```

and convert ALL occurrences of `<i>`...`</i>` to italicized text and `<b>`...`</b>` to bold text?

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to make sure you have the full Search/Replace dialogue box open.

Tick the `Use Wildcards` checkbox.

Find what: `\<b\>(*)\</b\>`

Replace with: `\1`

Then click the `Format` button and select bold.

Then replace all.

You can then do a similar procedure for italics.

For an explanation of Word's wildcards, see [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/add-power-to-word-searches-with-regular-expressions-HA001087305.aspx?redir=0).

Comment: Thank you so much!  did not know about that feature!